# Using D3 with websharper

Tags: d3.js, f#, websharper

I have looked at the extensions that websharper provides [here](http://www.websharper.com/SamplesPage). Is it possible to use [D3](http://d3js.org/) with websharper? If so are there any examples around?

Answer (score 4):

I started a D3.js wrapper a little while ago, you can use it and hopefully continue and extend it:

https://github.com/davidgrenier/Wrappers

Comment: I just redeployed the site on AppHarbor so you can see the result: http://davidgrenier.apphb.com/Chords

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about the WebSharper extensions. You can create your own extensions. There are various explanations online, some a bit out-dated, and the team is very friendly - feel free to ask them questions, either via e-mail or on FPish.